# Pycharm: how to input the intersection '∩' character in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I want to input the intersection '∩' character in Pycharm. After I copy the intersection '∩' character into pycharm, it became to 'n'.

Comment: I doubt that .. are you sure it's not just that the glyphs look similar in the font?

Comment: maybe you are right, I will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the intersection '∩' character and 'n' by the unicode, I found they are different although it looks similar.